# Fetching chain data to to website

Tags: web3js, nft

I am working on a marketplace NFT website. Should I use web3.js to track owners and other contract details when a user opens a specific website, or make a database that tracks those data? I want to get the owner, tokenId and some other built in read functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for simplicity, use web3js to track these data. It is difficult to ensure data from database will be up to date. For advance use case, create a program to monitor the block head and when detect token contracts, update or insert these token contracts information into database. Using database will yield better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the owners of an NFT using Moralis NFT API.

Here is an example of getting the owners using moralis

```
const Moralis = require("moralis").default;

const runApp = async () => {
  const { EvmChain } = Moralis.EvmUtils;

  await Moralis.start({
    apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
    // ...and any other configuration
  });

  const chain = EvmChain.ETHEREUM;
  const address = "0xed5af388653567af2f388e6224dc7c4b3241c544";


  const response = await Moralis.EvmApi.nft.getNFTOwners({
      address,
      chain,
  });
  console.log(response.raw);
};

runApp();
```

And this is what the results will look like.

```
[
    {
      "token_address": "0xed5af388653567af2f388e6224dc7c4b3241c544",
      "token_id": "7418",
      "amount": "1",
      "owner_of": "0x77e3e957082ca648c1c5b0f3e6aec00ab1245186",
      "token_hash": "74455e7bcbe36c4ef69341bdd0539086",
      "block_number_minted": "13992215",
      "block_number": "16765479",
      "contract_type": "ERC721",
      "name": "Azuki",
      "symbol": "AZUKI",
      "token_uri": "https://ipfs.moralis.io:2053/ipfs/QmZcH4YvBVVRJtdn4RdbaqgspFU8gH6P9vomDpBVpAL3u4/7418",
      "metadata": "{\"name\":\"Azuki #7418\",\"image\":\"ipfs://QmYDvPAXtiJg7s8JdRBSLWdgSphQdac8j1YuQNNxcGE1hg/7418.png\",\"attributes\":[{\"trait_type\":\"Type\",\"value\":\"Blue\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Hair\",\"value\":\"Silver Pixie\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Face\",\"value\":\"Red Fang Face Paint\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Clothing\",\"value\":\"Red Panda Hoodie\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Eyes\",\"value\":\"Striking\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Mouth\",\"value\":\"Smile\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Offhand\",\"value\":\"Bean Juice\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Background\",\"value\":\"Off White D\"}]}",
      "last_token_uri_sync": "2023-02-10T09:09:27.248Z",
      "last_metadata_sync": "2023-03-05T08:27:32.388Z",
      "minter_address": "0x07df20aa702114a9540c9eec83d6a2a92fbdf46d"
    },
    {
      "token_address": "0xed5af388653567af2f388e6224dc7c4b3241c544",
      "token_id": "2949",
      "amount": "1",
      "owner_of": "0x77e3e957082ca648c1c5b0f3e6aec00ab1245186",
      "token_hash": "4a02af90c1314abadf0aa15ff30447b6",
      "block_number_minted": "13992208",
      "block_number": "16765479",
      "contract_type": "ERC721",
      "name": "Azuki",
      "symbol": "AZUKI",
      "token_uri": "https://ipfs.moralis.io:2053/ipfs/QmZcH4YvBVVRJtdn4RdbaqgspFU8gH6P9vomDpBVpAL3u4/2949",
      "metadata": "{\"name\":\"Azuki #2949\",\"image\":\"ipfs://QmYDvPAXtiJg7s8JdRBSLWdgSphQdac8j1YuQNNxcGE1hg/2949.png\",\"attributes\":[{\"trait_type\":\"Type\",\"value\":\"Human\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Hair\",\"value\":\"Powder Blue Pigtails\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Headgear\",\"value\":\"Purple Kanzashi\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Neck\",\"value\":\"Chill Headphones\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Clothing\",\"value\":\"Tank Top with Jacket\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Eyes\",\"value\":\"Relaxed\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Mouth\",\"value\":\"Frown\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Background\",\"value\":\"Off White A\"}]}",
      "last_token_uri_sync": "2023-02-10T07:29:09.377Z",
      "last_metadata_sync": "2023-03-05T08:03:11.332Z",
      "minter_address": "0x98ebfcab380f83c3412f7036f1b1dc149c907c83"
    },
    {
      "token_address": "0xed5af388653567af2f388e6224dc7c4b3241c544",
      "token_id": "8766",
      "amount": "1",
      "owner_of": "0x1a51bcbc8d3642680d8267550f54e6e4cc5c4984",
      "token_hash": "80c5705c17437a741548d6898a8f2be7",
      "block_number_minted": "13992217",
      "block_number": "16765479",
      "contract_type": "ERC721",
      "name": "Azuki",
      "symbol": "AZUKI",
      "token_uri": "https://ipfs.moralis.io:2053/ipfs/QmZcH4YvBVVRJtdn4RdbaqgspFU8gH6P9vomDpBVpAL3u4/8766",
      "metadata": "{\"name\":\"Azuki #8766\",\"image\":\"ipfs://QmYDvPAXtiJg7s8JdRBSLWdgSphQdac8j1YuQNNxcGE1hg/8766.png\",\"attributes\":[{\"trait_type\":\"Type\",\"value\":\"Human\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Hair\",\"value\":\"Powder Blue Pigtails\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Clothing\",\"value\":\"Light Armor\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Eyes\",\"value\":\"Ruby\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Mouth\",\"value\":\"420\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Background\",\"value\":\"Red\"}]}",
      "last_token_uri_sync": "2023-02-11T01:04:12.853Z",
      "last_metadata_sync": "2023-03-05T08:03:11.331Z",
      "minter_address": "0x36abd0a112b5215c062a7a7125ba8cc23986bbe0"
    },
]
```

You can find a guide here: [How to get NFT owners](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/how-to-get-nft-owners-by-an-address)

Disclosure: I work at Moralis

Comment: How quick is this api system? How much time will it take vs a mysql database that is on the server?

Comment: Hi @NFT_king, Fetching data with moralis API is instant, getting the data yourself from the blockchain and storing it regularly might be time-consuming.